# Fieldset's legend inside of a div fails pa11y WCAG 2.0

Tags: html, css, section508, wcag2.0, pa11y

I have a fieldset like the following:

```
<fieldset>
 <div class="input-left">
  <legend class="legend-filters">Your full name:</legend>
 </div>
 <div class="input-right">
  <!-- some input here ... -->
 </div>
</fieldset>
```

I have the legend inside of a `div` to have more control over where it is placed. However, when it is inside of a `div`, it fails the pa11y WCAG 2.0 AA test, and the following error is returned:

`Fieldset does not contain a legend element. All fieldsets should contain a legend element that describes a description of the field group.`

When I remove it from a `div`, the error goes away:

```
<fieldset>
 <legend class="legend-filters">Your full name:</legend>
 <div class="input-right">
  <!-- some input here ... -->
 </div>
</fieldset>
```

Is this a false positive? Or does having the legend in a `div` actually make it inaccessible to some users?

Edit: applying my `div` class `input-left` to the `legend` element does what I need. However, I would still like to know at a compliance level what is required.

Comment: What do you mean with your need "to have more control over where it is placed"? Ideally the legend element is a direct descendant of the fieldset element. MDN says: "Permitted parents: A `<fieldset>` whose first child is this `<legend>` element". https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend Also this article helps to shed a light: https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2007/11/fieldsets-legends-and-screen-readers/

Comment: I had a false assumption that `legend` wasn't a block element by default. And the "permitted parent" reference in the MDN link is what I was looking for. Feel free to add a proper answer and I'll choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are leaning on HTML 5.1 (assuming so, though no DTD in your code), then `<legend>` must be the first child of `<fieldset>`:

> [Contexts in which this element can be used](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#contexts-in-which-this-element-can-be-used):
>
> As the first child of a [`<fieldset>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#elementdef-fieldset) element.

— https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#the-legend-element

If you drop your code into the [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea), then it will return an error:

> Error: Element legend not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
>
> From line 9, column 7; to line 9, column 37
>
> `t">↩      <legend class="legend-filters">Your f`
>
> Contexts in which element [`legend`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-legend-element) may be used:
>
> As the first child of a [`fieldset`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#elementdef-fieldset) element.